# Adobe Brakets - how to show "php hints"?

Tags: adobe-brackets

Don't know what's real name of this feature..
for example when I code in JS - brackets shows this little  menu with hints, but when i do php nothing pops up.

Is there any way to activate this help for php in Brakets?

Answer (score 0):

found an extension that partially resolve my problem. It doesn't describe possible vars for fn but at least works as auto-completer. 
https://github.com/Brackets-PHP/Brackets-PHP-SmartHints